# Problema con el MRO de python en herencia multiple

Tags: python, poo, herencia

Este es mi codigo de python:

```
 from typing import List

class Empleado:
    def __init__(self, nombre: str, salario: int):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.salario = salario
    
    def calcularBono(self):
        print(" Calculando bono para el empleado")

class Gerente(Empleado):
    def __init__(self, nombre: str, salario: int, departamento: str):
        super().__init__(nombre, salario)
        self.departamento = departamento

    def calcularBono(self):
        print(" Calculando bono para el gerente")

class Vendedor(Empleado):
    def __init__(self, nombre: str, salario: int, ventas: int):
        super().__init__(nombre, salario)
        self.ventas = ventas
    
    def calcularBono(self):
        print(" Calculando bono para el vendedor")

class EmpleadoEjecutivo(Gerente, Vendedor):
    def __init__(self, nombre: str, salario: int, departamento: str, ventas: int, accionesEjecutivas: List[str]):
        Gerente.__init__(self, nombre, salario, departamento)
        Vendedor.__init__(self, nombre, salario, ventas)
        self.accionesEjecutivas = accionesEjecutivas


    def realizarAccionEjecutiva():
        print(" El ejecutivo esta realizando una acción ejecutiva")

empleado1 = Empleado("Juan", 1000)
gerente1 = Gerente("Carlos", 2000, "Los Maderos")
vendedor1 = Vendedor("Guille", 3000, 25)
Tareas_ejecutivas = ["task1", "task2", "task3"]
empleadoEjecutivo1 = EmpleadoEjecutivo("Jorge", 6000, "Las cañitas", 40, Tareas_ejecutivas)

print(gerente1.nombre)
```

aqui mi problema radica en la clase "EmpleadoEjecutivo" y lo se porque al borrar esta clase la terminal de mi editor no me da ningun error de codigo, a mí no me parece que este llamando de forma incorrecta a las clases padre ni tampoco veo nada malo.

Los errores de codigo que arroja mi terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\saidn\OneDrive\Escritorio\proyectos de codigo\python\Ej 2 POO.py", line 41, in <module>
    empleadoEjecutivo1 = EmpleadoEjecutivo("Jorge", 6000, "Las cañitas", 40, Tareas_ejecutivas)
  File "c:\Users\saidn\OneDrive\Escritorio\proyectos de codigo\python\Ej 2 POO.py", line 29, in __init__
    Gerente.__init__(self, nombre, salario, departamento)
  File "c:\Users\saidn\OneDrive\Escritorio\proyectos de codigo\python\Ej 2 POO.py", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__(nombre, salario)
TypeError: Vendedor.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ventas'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código tiene dos puntos a resolver, por un lado tenemos herencia múltiple en la que los padres implementan el mismo método con distinta firma, en este caso el inicializador. Por otro lado muestra un clásico problema en herencia múltiple, el [problema del diamante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_diamante).

### El problema del diamante, razón de ser de `super()`

Vamos a partir de un ejemplo muy simplificado:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"Soy el metodo __init__ de A")
        
        
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"Soy el metodo __init__ de B")
        super().__init__()
        
        
class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"Soy el metodo __init__ de C")
        super().__init__()
        

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"Soy el metodo __init__ de D")
        B.__init__(self)
        C.__init__(self)
```

Es en esencia lo que ocurre en tu código, veamos que pasa si instanciamos `D`:

```
>>> D()
Soy el metodo __init__ de D
Soy el metodo __init__ de B
Soy el metodo __init__ de C
Soy el metodo __init__ de A
Soy el metodo __init__ de C
Soy el metodo __init__ de A
```

Están pasando cosas que no deberían, se llama a los inicializadores de `C` y `A` dos veces. Para entender porque pasa esto, hay que entender como `super` calcula a que método llamar en cada caso. Para entenderlo quizás sea útil recordar como había que llamar a `super` en Python 2, por ejemplo en el caso de `B`:

```
super(B, self).__init__()
```

El cálculo que hace `super` depende tanto de la clase desde la que se llama a `super` como del **árbol de ancestros de la instancia**. El primer componente, la clase donde se llama a `super`, viene determinado por el código fuente de esa clase (en Python 2 se lo pasábamos explícitamente) y es fijo. El segundo componente es la instancia y es mucho mas interesante porque es variable, aunque en nuestro caso esto es indiferente.

A grandes rasgos **`super` busca la clase (primer componente) en el MRO de la instancia y a partir de ese punto empieza resolver las llamadas a los métodos de los padres**.

Volvamos a nuestro ejemplo, en el `__init__` de `D` hacemos:

```
B.__init__(self)
```

esto llama explícitamente al inicializador de `B`, que a su vez ejecuta:

```
super().__init__()
```

que en realidad es:

```
super(B, self).__init__()
```

la clave esta en que `self` es la instancia de `D`, por lo que `super` busca en el MRO de `D` (que es `[D, B, C, A]`) a `B` y llama al `__init__` del siguiente en la lista después de el, sorpresa, ese es `C`... El `super` de `B` llama al `__init__` de `C`, eso justifica esta linea:

```
>>> D()
Soy el metodo __init__ de D
Soy el metodo __init__ de B
Soy el metodo __init__ de C <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Soy el metodo __init__ de A
Soy el metodo __init__ de C
Soy el metodo __init__ de A
```

Luego el `super` de `C` sigue el orden marcado por el MRO de `D` y llama al inicializador de `A`. Por ultimo se ejecuta el `C.__init__(self)` de `D`, que actúa igual que antes, solo que ahora el siguiente en el MRO de `D` después de `C` es `A`.

Esto traducido a tu caso concreto deriva en:

1. En `GerenteEjecutivo` llamas al inicializador de   `Gerente` explícitamente con `Gerente.__init__(self, nombre, salario, departamento)`
2. El incializador de `Gerente` a continuación ejecuta `super().__init__(nombre, salario)`. `super` mira el MRO de la instancia (instancia de `GerenteEjecutivo`) que es `[GerenteEjecutivo, Gerente, Vendedor, Empleado]` y busca la clase siguiente a `Gerente` en el (que es la clase desde donde se llama a `super`). Esa clase es `Vendedor`, por lo que resuelve que debe llamar a `Vendedor.__init__()`.
3. Cuando `Gerente` llama al `__init__` de `Vendedor` lo hace con la firma `__init__(nombre, salario)`, pero el inicializador de `Vendedor` tiene la firma  `__init__(self, nombre: str, salario: int, ventas: int)`, por lo que le falta un argumento, `ventas`, y aquí tenemos nuestra exepcion:

   > TypeError: Vendedor.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument:
   > 'ventas'

Volviendo a mi ejemplo simplificado, es fácil pensar que podemos resolver el problema de que `B` llame al `init` de `C` llamando explícitamente al inicializador de `A` y eliminando el culpable, `super`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"Soy el metodo __init__ de A")
        
        
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"Soy el metodo __init__ de B")
        A.__init__(self)
        
        
class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"Soy el metodo __init__ de C")
        A.__init__(self)
        

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"Soy el metodo __init__ de D")
        B.__init__(self)
        C.__init__(self)
```

Esto resolvería el problema de la necesidad de cooperación entre las clases hermanas (y tu error) pero nos estrellamos de lleno con el problema del diamante y terminamos llamando dos veces al inicializador de `A` (o `Empleado` en tu caso), lo cual puede ser muy malo dependiendo de su implementación:

> ```
> >>> D()
> Soy el metodo __init__ de D
> Soy el metodo __init__ de B
> Soy el metodo __init__ de A
> Soy el metodo __init__ de C
> Soy el metodo __init__ de A
> ```

`super` se creo en gran medida para resolver precisamente este problema, si dejamos que `super` se encargue:

```
class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"Soy el metodo __init__ de D, self es {self}")
        super().__init__()

>>> D
Soy el metodo __init__ de D
Soy el metodo __init__ de B
Soy el metodo __init__ de C
Soy el metodo __init__ de A
```

La linealización del MRO que hace `super` evita las llamadas duplicadas y solventa el problema del diamante. El problema en tu caso es que si usas super en `EmpleadoEjecutivo` solventas las llamadas duplicadas, pero sigues con el mismo problema por el que has creado la pregunta.

### Herencia múltiple con métodos comunes pero con distinta firma

En tu caso creo que deduzco la razón de por que llamas explícitamente a los inicializadores de ambos padres de `EmpleadoEjecutivo`, tienes el dilema de como pasar los argumentos adecuados al incializador de cada uno de ellos.

Esto se resuelve haciendo que las clases cooperen entre si, lo cual se consigue por lo general haciendo uso de argumentos variables arbitrarios con `**kwargs` y `*args`, permitiendo que los metodos reciban argumentos que no usan ellos, sino que van dirigidos a los metodos situados por encima de ellos en el MRO, por ejemplo:

```
from typing import List


class Empleado:
    def __init__(self, nombre: str, salario: int, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.salario = salario
    
    def calcular_bono(self):
        print(" Calculando bono para el empleado")


class Gerente(Empleado):
    def __init__(self, nombre: str, salario: int, departamento: str, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(nombre, salario, *args, **kwargs)
        self.departamento = departamento

    def calcular_bono(self):
        print(" Calculando bono para el gerente")


class Vendedor(Empleado):
    def __init__(self, nombre: str, salario: int, ventas: int, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(nombre, salario, *args, **kwargs)
        self.ventas = ventas
    
    def calcular_bono(self):
        print(" Calculando bono para el vendedor")


class EmpleadoEjecutivo(Gerente, Vendedor):
    def __init__(
            self, nombre: str, salario: int, departamento: str,
            ventas: int, acciones_ejecutivas: List[str]
            ):
        super().__init__(nombre, salario, departamento, ventas)
        self.acciones_ejecutivas = acciones_ejecutivas

    def realizar_accion_ejecutiva(self):
        print(" El ejecutivo esta realizando una acción ejecutiva")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    empleado = Empleado("Juan", 1000)
    gerente = Gerente("Carlos", 2000, "Los Maderos")
    vendedor = Vendedor("Guille", 3000, 25)
    tareas_ejecutivas = ["task1", "task2", "task3"]
    empleado_ejecutivo = EmpleadoEjecutivo(
        "Jorge", 6000,
        "Las cañitas",
        40,
        tareas_ejecutivas
        )
    
    print(empleado_ejecutivo.nombre)
```

Otra opción:

```
from typing import List


class Empleado:
    def __init__(self, nombre: str, salario: int, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.salario = salario
    
    def calcular_bono(self):
        print(" Calculando bono para el empleado")


class Gerente(Empleado):
    def __init__(self, nombre: str, salario: int, *, departamento: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(nombre, salario, **kwargs)
        self.departamento = departamento

    def calcular_bono(self):
        print(" Calculando bono para el gerente")


class Vendedor(Empleado):
    def __init__(self, nombre: str, salario: int, *, ventas: int, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(nombre, salario, **kwargs)
        self.ventas = ventas
    
    def calcular_bono(self):
        print(" Calculando bono para el vendedor")


class EmpleadoEjecutivo(Gerente, Vendedor):
    def __init__(
            self, nombre: str, salario: int, *,
            departamento: str,
            ventas: int,
            acciones_ejecutivas: List[str]):
        super().__init__(nombre, salario, departamento=departamento, ventas=ventas)
        self.acciones_ejecutivas = acciones_ejecutivas

    def realizar_accion_ejecutiva(self):
        print(" El ejecutivo esta realizando una acción ejecutiva")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    empleado = Empleado("Juan", 1000)
    gerente = Gerente("Carlos", 2000, departamento="Los Maderos")
    vendedor = Vendedor("Guille", 3000, ventas=25)
    tareas_ejecutivas = ["task1", "task2", "task3"]
    empleado_ejecutivo = EmpleadoEjecutivo(
        "Jorge", 6000,
        departamento="Las cañitas",
        ventas=40,
        acciones_ejecutivas=tareas_ejecutivas
        )
    
    print(empleado_ejecutivo.nombre)
```

En este caso se obliga a especificar los argumentos específicos de cada clase como argumentos *keyword* de forma que es fácil redirigirlos a donde corresponda con la ayuda de `**kwargs` y se evitan errores al instanciar.

---

### Edición

Como ya se explicaba arriba, por norma general hay dos enfoques para resolver el problema de tener dos clases padre con el mismo método y distinta firma, obviando el tercero que mucha gente defiende, evitar a toda costa la herencia múltiple. La primera opción es olvidarse de `super` y llamar a cada método de forma explicita:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        
class B:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        A.__init__(self, foo)
        B.__init__(self, bar)
```

Esto es lo que intentas en tu código, pero en tu caso tenemos el problema de la herencia en diamante, por lo que este enfoque en principio hace que se llamen los inicializadores mas de una vez si no se resuleve de alguna manera el problema, lo cual no es deseable.

La otra opción común es hacer uso de `super` y asegurarse de que trabajen de forma cooperativa. La idea es que cada inicializador consuma sus argumentos propios y pase el resto a las clases padre.

Aquí es donde entran en juego `*args` y `**kwargs`. Ambos permiten pasar un numero variable y opcional de argumentos a un método o función, `*args` para argumentos posicionales y `**kwargs` para argumentos por palabra clave.

`*args` captura todos los argumentos posicionales extra que se pasen al método y los almacena en una tupla mientras que `**kwargs` hace lo propio con los argumentos por palabra clave formando un diccionario:

```
def func(foo, *args, bar=0, **kwargs):
    print(f"Argumento posicional 'foo': {foo}")
    print(f"Argumentos posicionales variables: {args}")
    print(f"Argumento keyword 'bar': {bar}")
    print(f"Argumentos keyword variables: {kwargs}")

>>> func(4, "Hola", 5, bar=13, x=7, y=19)

Argumento posicional 'foo': 4
Argumentos posicionales variables: ('Hola', 5)
Argumento keyword 'bar': 13
Argumentos keyword variables: {'x': 7, 'y': 19}
```

Esto aplicado a nuestro problema de herencia múltiple:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, foo, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.foo = foo
        
class B:
    def __init__(self, bar, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bar = bar

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


c = C(foo="Hola", bar=3)
print(c.foo) # Hola
print(c.bar) # 3
```

Observa que **las clases padre deben estar diseñadas para trabajar de forma cooperativa**, en este caso es simplemente que **ambas llamen también a `super`** en sus métodos.

En cuanto al manejo de los argumentos, observa la secuencia:

1. Al inicializador de `C` le pasamos dos argumentos *keyword* (`foo` y `bar`), como el método no define estos argumentos ambos quedan recogidos en `**kwargs`, que es pasado al siguiente `__init__` a través de `super`, que es el de `A`.
2. El inicializador de `A` tiene el argumento *keyword* `foo` definido, por lo que el valor de `foo` pasado desde `A` se asocia a el, pero como `bar` no es un argumento de dicho método queda guardado en `**kwargs` y es pasado al siguiente en la cadena marcada por el MRO de `C`, que es el `__init__` de `B`.
3. El inicilizador de `B` tiene el argumento *keyword* `bar`, por lo que el valor de `bar` se asocia a el. En este punto `**kwargs` es un diccionario vacío, que es pasado al ultimo método llamado, el de `object` (clase base de la que herada todo objeto en Python).

Tambien podemos llamar en este caso a `C` con argumentos poscionales:

```
c = C("Hola", 3)
```

el funcionamiento es el mismo que el comentado antes, solo que los argumentos no usados se guardan en `*args` en este caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, e copiado y pegado el codigo y ahora todo parece funcionar corectamente, solo me pregunto si esta es la forma más convencional de resolver este problema, ahora solo debo ver un tutorial de lo que son los **kwargs para saber como y cuando usarlos. Desde lla muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Said, he editado la respuesta agregando otra posibilidad de implementación y al final algo mas de información de que son *args y **kwargs y como se usan en este caso para resolver este problema de herencia múltiple con métodos comunes con distinta firma. Espero que aclare algo el tema.

Comment: Si, me ayudo bastante ahora ya lo entiendo todo, desde ya muchas gracias por tu paciencia y mucha suerte